# create global variable though out forms

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am trying to save username and some other information as global variable through all windows forms starting from login form like `userName` I searched and come up with below code

first I create separate class called `globals` as below

```
public static class globals
{
    public static string userName { get; set; }
}
```

then I set that variable when login is successful as below

```
Checks.globals.userName = TB_USER_NAME.Text;
```

few question

- do I have to make property userName protected or maybe private?

  ```
  public static string userName { get; private set; }
  ```
- is that value will not be set again after first initialization ?
- is there anything better to do ?

Answer (score 5):

> I am trying to save username and some other information as global variable through all windows forms starting from login form like userName

This is considered a poor programming practice in C#. Taking a dependency on global state makes your program harder to reason about and harder to modify.

Consider another approach; if there are a lot of class instances in your program that need access to the same information, then they can all keep a reference to a state object, rather than referring to global state.

> first I create separate class called globals as below

If you are hell bent on using global variables, that's the right way to do it. But you should follow C# standards and call it `Globals`, not `globals`.

Similarly:

```
public static string userName { get; set; }
```

That should be `UserName`, not `userName`.

> then I set that variable when login is successful as below

```
Checks.globals.userName = TB_USER_NAME.Text;
```

Again, use proper C# naming conventions.  We do not use SHOUTING_SNAKES_EVERYWHERE in C#.

```
Checks.Globals.UserName = UserNameTextBox.Text;
```

> do I have to make property userName protected or maybe private?

You cannot make it protected; it's a static class!  Protected means accessible to derived classes and it is illegal to derive from a static class.

Making it private would make it inaccessible from outside the class, which is the opposite of what you want.

So, no, don't do that. Can you explain why you thought that might be a good idea? Because you have some false belief that should be disabused.

> is that value will not be set again after first initialization ?

It will be set as many times as you set it.  **That's what global state means, and why it is a bad idea**.  Now you have to ensure that your program only sets the value once, if that's what you want, and you have to ensure that **globally** in your program.  That's why global state is bad for maintainability: because it turns problems amenable to local analysis into problems that require whole-program analysis.

If you want to detect the bug where global state is set more than once, then make *more* global state: you need the global state of "my global state has been set once".  You can then check *that* state on the set, and crash the program if it is set more than once. Or ignore the second set, or whatever, if you prefer to hide your bugs rather than fix them.

> is there anything better to do?

Yes. Abandon the architecture that requires you to maintain global state. Maintain state in instance variables.

Comment: thanks for you helpful information I really appreciated just be patient my friend not everyone knows are experienced  :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking, "how can I enforce that a variable is set only one time". If that's the case, you can create a backing field to store the value, and in the property `set` method you can first check if the backing field is `null`. If it is, then set the value, and if it's not, don't do anything. In this manner, the backing field only gets set one time:

```
private static string _username = null;

public static string UserName
{
    get { return _userName; }
    set { if (_username == null) _username = value; }
}
```

Another option would be to make the `setter` private and provide a different method to set the value. This makes for an odd design, but it does make the `UserName` property read-only, which would prevent an accidental assignment (which would cause a compile-time error).

For example:

```
// UserName is a Read-Only property; it can't be assigned a value directly
public static string UserName { get; private set; }

// Anyone can change UserName here, but they have to intentionally call this method to do so
public static void SetUserName(string userName)
{
    UserName = userName;
}
```

Comment: i try it and I got an error when i set the value of it
ذThe property or indexer 'Checks.globals._userName' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessibleذ

Comment: yes, sorry, I had the setter as `private` for some reason, which was not my intent. It should work now. But please pay attention to Eric Lippert's advice. My answer may "solve" your problem, but I think the actual problem is bigger than this (program design).

Comment: i got an error on get part that says `{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}`

Comment: @sam: You have written a setter or a getter which calls itself.  Don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to make property userName protected or maybe private?

If you make property userName protected or maybe private you can't set the value by the property.

> is that value will not be set again after first initialization?

depend on your logic, need to carefully because it is a global value.

> is there anything better to do?

If you must use global, I would use [Singleton_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to do the global object.

This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict the instantiation to a certain number of objects

```
public class Globals
{
    private static Globals _obj;
    public static Globals Current {
        get {
            if (_obj == null)
                _obj = new Globals();
            return _obj;
        }
    }
    private Globals() { }

    private string _username;

    public string UserName { get { return _username; } }

    public void SetUserName(string userName) {
        this._username = userName;
    }
}
```

You can use `Globals.Current` to get the global object.
if you want to set `UserName` just call `SetUserName` method.

```
Globals.Current.SetUserName("test"); //set the username
Globals.Current.UserName; // get the username
```

Comment: A singleton is a nice approach because it allows you to wean yourself off of static global state gradually; you get all the dependent code written to handle state in an instance, and then whether the instance is a singleton or not is no concern of the consumer!